# LW and LB the same result

Tags: assembly, mips

I only want to have an array to calculate the sum of all numbers. I wasn't sure how to store each position into a variable, so I tried `lb $t5, ($s1)` and it worked, but when I changed it to `lw $t5, ($s1)` it works again. I know this isn't right, the `lw` command loads 4 bytes and the `lb` command 1 byte. I believe the proper solution is with `lw` because I increase the pointer 4 times. The `lb` souldn't work. The command is when the comment begins.

```
.data

arr: .word 1, 15, 0, -3, 99, 48, -17, -9, 20, 15

.text
main:

addi $s0, 10 #size=10
addi $t0, 0 #sum =0
addi $t4, 0

la $s1, arr

Loop:
slt $t3, $t4, $s0
beq $t3, $zero, End



lb $t5, ($s1) ##########   HERE  ##############
li $v0, 1 
move $a0, $t5


add $t0, $t0, $t5

add $t4, $t4, 1 
addi $s1, $s1, 4
j Loop


End:

li $v0, 1 
add $a0, $t0, $zero
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the description of `LB`:

> The contents of the 8-bit byte at the memory location specified by the effective address are fetched, **sign-extended**, and placed in GPR `rt`.

The range of a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) signed byte is -128..+127, so all the values in your array are small enough to be representable in one byte. That together with the fact that `LB` sign-extends and that your target "machine" (I'm guessing that you're using SPIM or MARS) is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) means that you'll get the same result when you use `LB` to load from your array as when you use `LW`.

For example, the value `-17` when written out as a hex word is `0xFFFFFFEF`. On a little-endian system the bytes of that word are stored with the least significant byte first, i.e. `0xEF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF`. So when you `lb` from that element you get `0xEF` which is sign-extended into `0xFFFFFFEF`.

Comment: I can see it now. So, if I had larger numbers, should I have used lw?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use `lw` to get the correct values.